# Change checkboxlist rendering in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label, html, checkboxlist

By Default CheckBoxlist control in asp.net render as a table with each row has one input type checkbox and one label .

```
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_0">1</label>
```

I want to change label into span tag .

should i use jquery to find each element of that table and change that or there any other property i am missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) for this

```
        $("label").replaceWith("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
```

Comment: Hello @zeetee thanks for it. its works for me. i Used the following lines   <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function () {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars label').each(function () {

                $(this).replaceWith("<span class='stars'>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
              
            });
        });

    </script>